# What train_dir to use for Tensorflow imagenet_train to train from scratch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, imagenet

I am following the below page

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception

I got to the point I have to run:

`bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train --num_gpus=1 --batch_size=32 --train_dir=/tmp/imagenet_train --data_dir=/tmp/imagenet_data`

However, I got below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/demo/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_train.py", line 41, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/demo/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/demo/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_train.py", line 35, in main
    tf.gfile.DeleteRecursively(FLAGS.train_dir)
  File "/home/demo/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 420, in delete_recursively
    pywrap_tensorflow.DeleteRecursively(compat.as_bytes(dirname), status)
  File "/home/demo/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/home/demo/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: /tmp/imagenet_train
```

My `DATA_DIR` is `/tmp/imagenet_data` from previous step `bazel-bin/inception/download_and_preprocess_imagenet "${DATA_DIR}"`

But what would be my `train_dir`? The doc doesn't mention it? Look like an empty folder is incorrect.

Comment: I'd suggest you raise an issue on the Github repository you linked us to. Someone might know the answer here but it would be more realistic to ask directly the people who coded the library :)

Comment: Things are going in circle. I posted in Github and was told to post in Stackoverflow https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1459

Comment: I see the point they make... I will try to get a better look at your issue once I get back from work ! But hopefully someone would have solved it by them :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, it works if I set the path of --train_dir=/tmp. Also, you have the processed dataset in the same directory. The --train_dir and --data_dir should not coincide with each other.

**Location of where to place the ImageNet data DATA_DIR=$HOME/imagenet-data**

Can you tell me if you are still running into problems after changing the directory?

Answer (score 0):

`--train_dir` is the path to an empty directory where the model checkpoints and events files are stored as the model is trained.

Comment: I tried that as well and have `/tmp/imagenet_train` as an empty directory but it still gave me the same error. Is there anything special about this directory? I have permission to it as the user.